# shresoft VPN reconnect on internet connection failure

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, vpn

I am using a batch file for shrewsoft VPN connect-disconnect, my requirements are 
1. I am doing a ping test, if ping is failed (internet failure or disconnection issues) then VPN should disconnect and the moment the Internet is ON and ping starts, VPN should connect automatically. So I am looking for an infinite ping loop which will connect or disconnect VPN

2. I want to run shrew VPN minimsed all the time or better in system tray

I am using this batch but when internet is off (connection failure) VPN disconnects, but I want code to reconnect the VPN once internet connection is reinstated.

@echo off
start /min "vpn" "C:\Program Files\ShrewSoft\VPN Client\ipsecc.exe" -r "testVPN.vpn" -u username -p password -a
:loop
    echo testing IP address
    ping 121.244.116.222 >nul || (
       echo ping failure - disconnecting
      taskkill /T /F /IM "ipsecc.exe"

)
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
goto :loop

Answer (score 0):

I've built and open sourced an app to do exactly that, Check it out at https://github.com/CamW/shrew-reconnect if you're interested. You can build from code or just download the installer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try using "expect" as described in https://sakhnik.com/2016/11/21/automatic-vpn.html

Maybe you can adopt this.

Comment: Please explain the solution here, don't just post a link

Comment: It is really good explained in the link. Should i copy it in there?
It#s about automating cmd-line software that is not using Std-in or Std-out for control.